# Continuously loop thru a database table until record found, then delete record.

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have this method that has to scan a database table Announce continuously until a new record appears it compares it to a record from another table and if it matches it Deletes it from table announce and it continues to search until anothe record appears. Is there a better way of doing this instead of using a while(true) statement. Note: I am using Sqlserver

```
 //Begin method
    public void Begin()
    {
        string announce;
        double announceID;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AnnounceConnString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                  //Selects Last record written to tblAnnounce 
                    SqlCommand sqlcommandStart = new SqlCommand("AnnounceSelect", connStr);
                    sqlcommandStart.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    connStr.Open();

                    SqlDataReader dr = sqlcommandStart.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            announce = dr["AnnounceID"].ToString();
                            announceID = Convert.ToDouble(announce);
                            //Compares Values
                            //if it matches then DELETE record from TblAnnounce
                        }
                        connStr.Close();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        connStr.Close();

                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string exception = ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(exception
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a database trigger?

Comment: No idea of how to use that. Where do I begin?

Comment: Would it make more sense to pass the target value to the stored procedure as a parameter and let it do the searching?  It can delete the row, if matched, and return an appropriate flag.  Or, if you need to handle recovery, mark the row "in process" so that you can delete it later.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this programmatically?

Comment: I would definitely go with a trigger in this situation.  You're constantly pinging your database from your program to see if there's a new record that matches.  Put an after-insert trigger on the table and move all that work and logic to the database.

Comment: @Tim I do not know if I can use a trigger in this situation. I have to compare two values from different tables and then if they match I have to display the matching value in the FORM and then delete it from the Table Announce.

Comment: If you frequently insert a lot of data (e.g. if a remote GPS device is constantly sending new locations), then be cautious when you use trigger. It might lead to deadlocks.

Comment: @Apollo - In that case, HABO's comment is something to look into.  What happens if the newly inserted record doesn't have a match in tblAnnouncements?  Is it left there indefinitely?  If there is a match, are the records in both tables deleted?  How frequently do these inserts occur, and does the deletion need to happen as immediately as possible in the case of a match?

Comment: Best is to use a trigger. Two triggers on each table should also be considered. As both tables are updated randomly which will make sure each new matching record is deleted.

Comment: Am not inserting any records only reading from 2 tables. If table A ID = to TAble B OtherID, then Delete TAble B OtherID, contniue to look for new records.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than check continuously for insert record you can easily handle this on insert. check before insert in other table and if exist you can ignore the insert.

Or you can use insert triger for this table in database level to handle the delete record if matching record found.

by C# code you can do this using [CLR Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093%28SQL.100%29.aspx). check the sample at the end of MSDN page.

### EDIT

AS per your new comments you are not inserting data, but you want to compare and delete records. you can do as below. change the sql query as you need

```
using (var sc = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
{
    sc.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from TableB where OtherID in (select distinct ID from tableA)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Am not inserting any records only reading from 2 tables. If table A ID = to TAble B OtherID row, then Delete TAble B OtherID, contniue to look for new records.

Comment: The problem is not deleting. How to keep the program running is the question. Here is my original question, Is there a better way of doing this instead of using a while(true) statement. Note: I am using Sqlserver

Comment: @Apollo do you have time interval to run this task? like every 5 min?

Comment: this task checking constantly for a new record. So no time interval. My question is, is there are a better way than doing this with an infinite while(true) loop to check constantly for records.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do here?  If you are accepting values into the announce and deleting them if they already exist then a trigger is fine.  However, you can also write a query or view to just select the rows where there is or is not a matching row.  Both these ways mean you don't actually have to constantly monitor the table at all.

Another way is to consider using a dependency

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx

alternatively, depending on your situation, a queue to get the message into your announce table might be a better model.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx

instead of a constantly scanning process.  You can do the logic as the new message arrives.

I think the dependency will be the most suited to you from what you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

// you can use inner join in delete statement in T-Sql :

```
DELETE FROM tbl1
FROM table1 AS tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.Id=tble2.Id
```